# tail -f is not updating on AFP mounted share

Tags: macos, tail

I am running Mac OS 10.6.8

I have mounted a network drive, whose file I need to watch. I was planning on using tail.

When I run the following:

```
tail -f /Volumes/Cache-A/TransferLog.txt
```

I end up with a `tail` report that looks correct, however it does not update.
(it is as if I had typed `tail` rather than `tail -f` except that the shell does not come back - I have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to get back to where I can type)

The Cache-A drive is a linux system, and I have confirmed that when I run the command

```
tail -f TransferLog.txt
```

it updates as expected.

Is there a reason why the OS X tail command is not updating properly? Is it because it is a network mounted drive rather than a local file? Would mounting via NFS help? (<strike>I cannot mount via AFP</strike>)

EDIT:
Turns out I CAN mount via AFP, although the same issue is occurring. 
(I'm not so smart with wireshark - but I'll look that over as well)

Comment: Try checking with Wireshark whether the SMB server actually *sends* file change notifications, so that you'll know which side is the problem at. (NFS doesn't even have change notification, so don't bother with it.)